# pgsearch for whole words with multisearchable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pg-search

Please pardon me if this is a duplicate question.  I am a junior level rails developer and have recently installed pgsearch on my app.

I have the pg_trgm contrib package installed (:trigram and :dmetaphone).

When I search for "how to interview" I receive results such as "discrimina**to**ry" with "to" highlighted, or "**how**ever" with "how" highlighted.

Here's my initializer:

```
PgSearch.multisearch_options = { 
 :using => { 
   :trigram => {
    :threshold => 0.5
   },
   :dmetaphone => {
    :any_word => true, 
    :sort_only => true
   },
   :tsearch => { 
    :prefix => true,
    :any_word => true,
    :dictionary => "english",
    :normalization => 2 
   }
 }
}
```

**How does one modify their pg_search to search whole words?**

*Forgot to mention, I am using multisearchable :against => [:title, :body] in my model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my reading from the github repo, you need to remove the line `:prefix => true,`

but in general, maybe remove all of the options that you don't understand and layer them on one by one and see how they affect the results.